# How to make set headers persist in Express Node JS

Tags: node.js, express, http-headers, jwt

My node JS application involves setting a Jason Web Token to the response header at login so that I can use this JWT to verify the user when accessing restriced pages.

My question is how to get this header to persist. Currently I am setting the header at registration and login routes using code such as this:

```
    // Login Handle
router.post("/login", async (req, res, next) => {


  const user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
  if (!user) return res.status(400).send("Email or password is incorrect");

  const validPassword = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password);
  if (!validPassword) return res.status(400).send("Invalid email or password.");

  const token = user.generateAuthToken();

  res.set('x-auth-token', token).redirect('/dashboard');

});
```

Here is my authentication middleware that I am trying to get working:

```
function auth(req, res, next) {
    const token = req.header('x-auth-token');
    if(!token) return res.status(401).send("Access denied. No token provided");

    // if the token is valid it will return the decoded payload
    try {
        const decoded = jwt.verify(token, jwtPrivateKey);
        req.user = decoded;
        next();
    }
    catch(ex) {
        res.status(400).send("Invalid token.");
    }
```

I can see in the network tab on chrome dev tools that the header is correctly being set with the JWT. However, as soon as the page is refreshed or I visit a different page the header disappears.

Do I need to use `res.set('x-auth-token', token).render('foo')` on every route? It seems like this wouldn't be a great solution.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?